# Gaia Gbp - Grp: why does it get larger as star gets redder?

Tags: temperature, white-dwarf, gaia, absolute-magnitude

As an enthusiastic amateur scientist, I'm plowing my way through a cool [Gaia](http://sci.esa.int/gaia/) [DR2](https://www.cosmos.esa.int/web/gaia/dr2)-based paper, ["An Empirical Measurement of the Initial-Final Mass Relation with Gaia White Dwarfs"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.05849.pdf). I'm doing all right, but have hit a roadblock: understanding the meaning of the stellar color value G<sub>BP</sub> - G<sub>RP</sub>.

G<sub>BP</sub> is the blue photometry value, and G<sub>RP</sub> is the red photometry value, so G<sub>BP</sub> - G<sub>RP</sub> is the difference between the two, giving a number broadly encoding the star's color. Here's a graph from the paper that uses this value:

[image: Gaia graph; absolute magnitude versus GBP - GRP]

It's a graph of white dwarf ("WD") color versus absolute magnitude. On the left, the absolute magnitude M<sub>G</sub> increases (downwards) as the star grows dimmer, and across the bottom the color G<sub>BP</sub> - G<sub>RP</sub> increases (rightwards) as the star grows redder. Hence the slope of the curve; as a WD cools, it gets smoothly dimmer and redder.

But wait! as a star gets redder, the the "blue" brightness should become relatively smaller than the "red" brightness, right? So, the G<sub>BP</sub> - G<sub>RP</sub> value should get smaller and smaller, right? But that's the opposite of what this graph (and other graphs in the paper) apparently shows.

Should G<sub>BP</sub> - G<sub>RP</sub> get larger as a star cools and gets redder? Where am I confused? (I'm assuming the professionals aren't all confused...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But you demonstrate that you know the answer to this question! Fainter objects have larger magnitudes. So as the white dwarf becomes cooler and redder, its blue magnitude $(G_{BP})$ grows by more than its red magnitude $(G_{RP})$ and the colour-index $(G_{BP} - G_{RP})$ becomes larger. This is very similar to the commonly used $B-V$ colour, which is larger for cooler stars.

Comment: So, the "G" is a magnitude (larger <=> dimmer), not a brightness (larger <=> brighter)? That would explain it. (That would also explain why the difference is a useful near-zero value; it corresponds to a ratio of the brightness.)

Comment: Mind if I edit your answer to more clearly include the info in my comment? (Or, edit it yourself if you like.)

Comment: A confirming source: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.0815.pdf cites Gbp and Grp as "Gaia magnitudes".

Answer (score 0):

Magnitude decreases when it is brighter. So G_BP value goes larger, G_RP goes smaller when the star gets redder and less blue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).